reverse_cuthill_mckee in scipy: how to avoid zeros on diagonal and how to get back original matrix?
I am trying to use reverse_cuthill_mckee to reduce the bandwidth of my sparse, symmetric, complex matrix and thus improve its condition number. But As I am testing on simpler matrices, it seems the reverse_cuthill_mckee may put 0 on the diagonal of the matrix. This will lead to instability in the matrix inversion.
Is there a way to avoid getting zeros on the diagonal when using reverse_cuthill_mckee ?
Here's the example snippet which produces zeros on the diagonal.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import reverse_cuthill_mckee

graph = np.array([
                  [5, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                  [1, 6, 2, 0, 0],
                  [0, 2, 4, 0, 5],
                  [0, 0, 0, 7, 6],
                  [1, 0, 5, 6, 1]
                 ])

graph_csc = sp.csc_matrix(graph)
cmindx=reverse_cuthill_mckee(graph_csc, symmetric_mode=True)
rm_graph_csc=graph_csc[cmindx]

When looking at
rm_graph_csc.toarray()

We get
array([[1, 6, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 4, 0, 5],
       [5, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 5, 6, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 6]], dtype=int32)

Element (2,2) in python indices or (3,3) in regular index notations is 0. Is it possible to avoid this ?

what's cmindx?  Did you try permuting both rows and columns?

According to the docs cmindx is the permulation array for both the rows and columns.  The resulting array should remain symmetric.
In [145]: cmindx
Out[145]: array([1, 2, 0, 4, 3])

In [146]: graph_csc[cmindx[:,None],cmindx]
Out[146]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 15 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [147]: _.A
Out[147]: 
array([[6, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 4, 0, 5, 0],
       [1, 0, 5, 1, 0],
       [0, 5, 1, 1, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 6, 7]], dtype=int32)

This is symmetric with 0s moved away from the diagonal as much as possible.
You can undo the permuation by sorting the cmindx
In [164]: idx = np.argsort(cmindx)

In [165]: idx
Out[165]: array([2, 0, 1, 4, 3], dtype=int64)

In [166]: _147[idx[:,None],idx]
Out[166]: 
array([[5, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 6, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 4, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 6],
       [1, 0, 5, 6, 1]], dtype=int32)

